# Adjusting keyboard sensitivity in a command line terminal?

Tags: linux, keyboard, console

When using a tty login shell by entering `Ctrl-Alt-F1` from an Ubuntu 12.04 install on a laptop the keyboard seems overly sensitive and if my finger lingers for a moment on a button I end up with repeats of the same letter. Is there a way to adjust keyboard sensitivity that would influence the keyboard response when accessing a login shell from a tty instance?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is called 'keyboard auto repeat rate' and you can set it with `kbdrate` Mine is set to:

```
$ sudo kbdrate
Typematic Rate set to 10.9 cps (delay = 250 ms)
```

You can set same with:

```
$ sudo kbdrate -r 10.9 -d 250
Typematic Rate set to 10.9 cps (delay = 250 ms)
```

Check the manual page for exact options:

```
man kbdrate
```

Unsure where the default setting is done, but `/etc/rc.local`, your `.bash_profile`, `.profile` or `.bashrc` sounds like a good place.

Comment: `xset r rate 1` is more power full command line `kbdrate -r 1000 -d 1`. One thing is more that "kbdrate" for "cUI" and "xset" for "GUI".

Answer (score 29):

*(I noticed a complaint that [`kbdrate` might have a max limitation](http://suso.suso.org/xulu/Setting_your_keyboard_repeat_rate_under_X.). Not sure how true it still is)*.

I use `xset r rate 250 60` to accomplish speedups to my liking. I happen to put that in my `~/.i3/config` (for [i3wm](https://i3wm.org/)) but I used to have it working in my `~/.xinitrc` for `startx` to pick up. The `xset` invocation should apply to everything running in X.

(I’d be curious to hear if there’s any reason to prefer `kbdrate` or `xset`.)

Comment: kbdrate seemed to not work.  xset was perfect and now incorporated into my xinitrc.  https://github.com/Zamicol/dotfiles/commit/fbd635a513fb13ccc0b00d441172454746b61dfb#diff-ec5d2513d875a661c8fda505cee8529bR11

Comment: Add `atkbd.softrepeat=1` on the kernel command line.

Comment: This answer is invalid for the question.  The question was for Linux TTY. The command "xset" is only for X11.

Answer (score 12):

**Add `atkbd.softrepeat=1` on the kernel command line if you need fast repeat rate and low delay.**

Without the trick, the hardware delay is limited by 250 ms, and the maximum repeat rate is 30. For the most people who use arrows for navigation in text editor or command line, the rate is too low, and the delay is too high.

Meanwhile, in Visual Studio, developers use an option called "double effective keyboard repeat rate" in the Visual Assist plugin. It should be a nice reason for the existence of the option.

Working with Linux without X could be a nice time saver, because you don't use your browser.

If you've spent more than a working day googling how to make `kbdrate` to accept the slower delay than 250 ms, the answer should help.

Comment: I found really weird thing, if while X is running you switch to virtual tty by pressing Alt+Control+F3 for example, `kbdrate` will accept lower values, and also will execute in few ms. While if you use kbdrate from xterm or other X based terminal like gnome or xfce it will not accept anything lower than 30/250 and might take seconds to complete.