# Adjusting keyboard delay in a TTY?

Tags: debian, keyboard, tty, delay

When using a TTY login shell by entering e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> on Debian Jessie. There is an inhuman fast delay, specifically, these values are set (250ms):

```
root@VB-NB-Debian:~# kbdrate
Typematic Rate set to 10.9 cps (delay = 250 ms)

vlastimil@VB-NB-Debian:~$ sudo kbdrate
Typematic Rate set to 10.9 cps (delay = 250 ms)
```

I don't understand, since I have a "normal" 810ms set in my KDE system. Still, in Xterm the `kbdrate` says I have a delay of 250ms set.

Anyway, this is not the point. I need to permanently change the delay for all TTYs. Can you help me with that?

I found this: [Adjusting keyboard sensitivity in a command line terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58651/adjusting-keyboard-sensitivity-in-a-command-line-terminal) but it doesn't guide me. What exactly shall I do?

So, the question is, how to set the delay (not interested in the rate) once and for all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the `kbdrate` program only affects the rate in the Linux console outside of X windows and I think has to do with the BIOS keyboard repeat rate. The program you can use from a terminal in X windows to set the one that will control X windows terminals like Xterm is called `xset`. Use it like this:

```
xset r rate 810 30
```

I don't use KDE so I'm not sure if this really works in KDE, but it works in Xfce.